# Php mail function when sent to hotmail received it as encrypted

Tags: php, email, encryption

I have created a standalone email templater software. it all works on gmail, yahoo and even on outlook and other business emails. But the problem is on hotmail . When i tried to send some sample email,on receiving it automatically encrypts the sent email . something like this

> †Ù¥…æ¶+exK« „ÒJÖ«µêÒãÚrF {ûb¶W¬·)^µìmrë-r‰h­Ê%¢¶åiÉ?²Ü¥{ø^iÖèw'b¾) ²·&j       Úµë–+^r‰¿Šf zÏÒà@4Ñ À™à…è †ÝúÒœp‰Ûa÷Í)Ç÷b¾—%jË-{\ºË\¢Z+&¬wúirV¬²×±µË¬µÊ%¢±Þ­è¬¶¢ú+™«b¢{ajÜ¨º·ª¹ë-y×è®‰èº»-®‰à²–§²Ü¥yÊ%¢ºÞtK« „ÒJÖ«µêÒãÚrF >>{û)jì¶º'ºÓ†+)iÉè¬uë"‚w~Šì™©ejwfyØ®™»¬Šw¬²)ÀºËkjXš¶‡(š—­z‰í…ê'–)Þ™ªäz×è®Ø^š‹-i÷è

heres my code:

```
<?php
    $to = $_GET['email'];
    $nameOfClient = $_GET['username'];
    $StarterPackage = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample Email Templater</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <span style='color:black;'>
     This package is designed for small and medium business in Australia to 
     compete on the online market for the most affordable price. If you 
     don't have a website yet, it's the best timing for your business to 
     have one now. If you already have a website it's the perfect time to 
     boost your ranking online for your business advantage and needs.</span>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1";
    $headers[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
    $result = mail($to,$subject,$StarterPackage,implode("\r\n", $headers)); 
?>
```

Comment: `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` why this?

Comment: Is there any problem with that sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting headers as follows since you are using html elements in the body

```
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1";
```

also check by removing the following code if any problem still exists

```
$headers[] = "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64";
```

Comment: i've been there and it's no use actually.

Comment: can you help me 1 more thing guys?

Comment: sure, what is it?

Comment: i don't see any image on hotmail :( why is that and on gmail it always going to spam.